# Ошибка сериализации при передачи значения

Tags: android, serializable

есть класс

```
    public class MyClass implements Serializable {
    private long id;
    private String title, specification, task, event;
    private int start, end;
}
```

Надо его передать как параметр при запуске активности из фрагмента.
Делаю так:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("args", param);
Intent i = new Intent(this, ViewSpec.class);
i.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(i);
```

Получаю ошибку java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object.
Что не так не пойму?

Comment: Лучше реализуйте интерфейс `Parcelable`. Это более каноничный путь для Android. К тому же, он на порядок быстрее.

Comment: А `param` у вас точно экземпляр `MyClass` ?

Comment: Вообщем я реализовал в классе методы writeObject и readObject и все заработало. Спасибо.

Comment: Но, всё же, перепишите лучше на `Parcelable`, он раз в 10 быстрее.